# Как перейти с swiper js 4 версии на 9

Tags: javascript, swiper

Столкнулся с проблемой: при реализации слайдера на 4 версии swiperjs все работает корректно, при запуске на 9 версии слайдер ломается.
Приложу код в [codepen](https://codepen.io/fbsnh45/pen/GRYKVrr), в блоке html закомментировал подключение к 9 версии.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: А что ломается то, вроде как всё работает. Просто стили прописанные в старом swiper.css исчезают, так как в новом они не внесены. Кто-то до этого писал css прямо в swiper.css и теперь загружая новый swiper.css они исчезают. В общем стили от нового swiper.css не грузите, оставьте старые, а заменить можете только js

Comment: Слайдер не ограничивается по длине, он заходит за пределы экрана

Comment: Я и говорю, стили вы отключаете от старого swiper.css, а в нём как раз стили ограничивающие его по ширине. Стили оставьте от старого слайдера, а js поменяйте.